# Visual Studio project reference that isn't version specific at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

We have a multi-project solution.  The references between projects are done as Project References rather than Assembly Reference (as one would expect).  This works fine for our deployment, but creates a runtime dependency that is version specific. The trouble is that we would like to start creating hot fix installers that only update the specific dlls that changed.  Updating all dlls is not an option for our current customer situation.

The 'Specific Version' property on project references is disabled and i'm having trouble finding out a workaround other than switching to Assembly References and using Choose blocks in the csproj to switch between debug/release bins based on build config.

Is there another alternative to allow any version to be used at runtime?

Comment: The app.config file should be able to redirect calls from one version to another.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That's a good point. We use redirects for a few other things and could make use of it here as well. I haven't verified it would work for this situation yet, but I presume it would. Though, I am hoping for something that is effectively maintenance free (like the SpecificVersion=false setting for assembly references)

Comment: Are all the assemblies strong named?

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem, you still need a Magic Eight Ball that knows what version of these DLLs that the user has installed.  There is nothing built into the IDE or MSBuild to provide that oracle, you have to track that yourself.  Nothing subtle either, forgetting to increment the [AssemblyVersion] is a very basic mishap.  A dedicated deployment server with a build engineer pushing updates is the common approach.  That makes your "current customer situation" entirely your problem and not his, like it should be.

Comment: That was a bit ambiguous, it should be the customer's problem.  Their IT staff should push updates, typically after reviewing and testing changes.  If they don't want to have this staff then be sure to make them pay for yours :)

Answer (score 4):

MAINTENANCE FREE

The approach we went with was to **set the Assembly version to be a fixed number** and only update the File version when we build.(we used to keep both in sync with each other).  We went with this approach since it was maintenance free and let us keep our references by Project.

The assembly version is what .net uses to find specific versions of a dependent dll.  File version is what will display if you view property details on a file via windows explorer.

If you want to be able to hotfix any dll then you'll need to update all of your Assembly References to be `versionSpecific=false` and set all of your projects to have a fixed assembly version.  If you only want to be able to hotfix specific project dlls then you need only fix the assembly version on those projects.  The referencing projects could then keep whatever assembly version scheme you want.

Assembly version is set in `ProjectFolder/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs`.  We've now fixed ours to be 1.0.0.0 and only increment the file version when building.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.45678")]
```

Answer (score 1):

REQUIRES MAINTENANCE

If you are unable to set a fixed Assembly version then another approach can be to use a File reference.  The trouble here is that the path your project dlls will vary based on your active build configuration (debug vs release).  To get around this you can make your reference be conditional based on the config.

The major downside being that you'll need to maintain the build sequence manually.  Also, if you add a new project then you'll need to remember to use these dynamic references again.

```
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Your.AssemblyName">
          <HintPath>..\Your.AssemblyName\bin\x86\release\Your.AssemblyName.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Your.AssemblyName">
          <HintPath>..\Your.AssemblyName\bin\x86\debug\Your.AssemblyName.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
      </ItemGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>
```

You can also leave Debug as being a project reference if so desired, this would allow you to see what build sequence visual studio automatically generates due to the project references. You would then be able to mimic that sequence for your release config.